# как работает cloudflare?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cloudflare

Хай. Может кто-то объяснить как работает cloudflare... Не могу понять несколько моментов...

1. Когда чистый (новый) браузер посылает запрос, то на вкладке network нету никаких дополнительных запросов (редиректов), а сразу появляется страница... Если же посылать запрос с каким-нибудь curl (или тому подобное) с учетом всех заголовком на примере браузерного запроса, то появляется блокировка cloudflare... вопрос в чем разница то?
2. Как cloudflare определяет разницу между браузером и нативным запросом?
3. Насколько я понял, cloudflare загружает js, этот js отрабатывает и если все ок, то ajax запросом подгружает саму страницу (но не могу понять, ибо ajax запросов в браузере нету, один запрос который получает html), тогда как работает по другому?

Если кто-то может объяснить буду благодарен, спасибо (гуглил и много перечитал, и все равно не могу понять)

Comment: Вероятно, разница в том, что curl палит себя в юзер-агенте, и cloudflare считает это подозрительным и включает блокировку. Если же cloudflare не видит ничего подозрительного, то блокировок нет и никаких js тоже нет

Comment: @andreymal user-agent и все остальные заголовки идентичные браузеру

Comment: А IP-адрес идентичный?

Comment: @andreymal само собой, что да. все идентично, тестирую и перепробовал уже кучу всего и не могу понять как cloudflare определяет разницу...

Comment: можно посмотреть описание [в справке cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/how-cloudflare-works)

Comment: @Grundy смогли бы вы объяснить эту справку на уровне браузера? как браузер понимает, что все ок, а нативный запрос нет?

Comment: @bsbak, браузер никак не понимает. запрос анализирует cloudflare: ip, запрашиваемый ресурс, частоту запроса, а так же могут быть какие-то особенные правила

Comment: @Grundy это понятно, так как cloudflare определяет обычный это запрос или браузер, если в обычном запросе есть все заголовки, что и в браузере? Если в браузере смотреть network, то видно, что есть запрос и сразу возвращается html страница, то есть браузер не посылает 2-й запрос пока не получит ответ основной страницы, парсит и потом отправляет другие запросы...

Comment: @bsbak _если в обычном запросе есть все заголовки, что и в браузере_ - возможно не все ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯